# BigQuery Java Streaming read?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking to see if I'm just using the wrong pattern for reading from big query.

I'd like to stream the read requests so I'm not loading all the data in memory.

This is what I'm doing right now.

```java
 String columnsRequested = Joiner.on(", ").join(columns);
       String query = String.format("SELECT %s FROM `%s`, UNNEST(hits) AS hits", columnsRequested, getSource(realTableName, dataSetId));


       QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration
           .newBuilder(query)
           .setUseLegacySql(false)
           .build();
// Once I have the job config simply execute:
     QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = constructQuery(dataSetId, tableName, columns);
            TableResult res = bigquery.query(queryConfig);
            return res;
```

then in a different code path i read the result.

```
  for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {

    // read data, manipulate and write each line to a CSV file.
  }
```

Each Result is around a gig of data that we're reading, and my memory footprint looks around that size.  The CSV writer doesn't keep anything in mem, so my leaning towards BigTable java lib being at fault.

Is there a better way of querying the data where the results are streamed rather than loaded in memory?

**NOTE**: I'm specifically asking about read operations.  The write I did find references but doesn't help my case.

Comment: Did you mean BigQuery, not Bigtable?

Comment: Sorry about that yes, bigQuery!